# Creating multi auth middleware vs just reading role from user table?

Tags: laravel, authentication, security

It seems to be a lot of work to create a [multi role auth middleware](https://laratutorials.com/laravel-9-multiple-user-role-based-authentication-example/). Is it terribly insecure to just add a `role check` inside of your `authentication` function during login like so:

```
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->get();
        $role = $user[0]->role;

        if ($role === 'admin') {
            return redirect()->route('admin.home');
        }
    }
```

What benefits does the mentioned middleware?

Comment: The article you link to uses permissions. So the question you should ask yourself should be: "Do I want to split roles into permissions?". Both options should not affect the security.

Comment: Don't confuse authentication and authorization.  Having multiple guards is an unnecessary complication.  A user is a user.  Its their roles and permissions that determine what that user can do.  NEVER log someone in using middleware.

Comment: Check https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction - you don't have to make a login based on their role or permissions. Just login the user, and then apply a middleware on the routes based on their role or permission (you can as well check their roles and/or permissions inside the controller). Roles and permissions are what a user can or can't do in an app (it has nothing to do with authentication).